# Expresión regular para hasta 50 letras del español

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Cuál es expresión regular para JavaScript que pueda contener letras con los caracteres del español ya sea mayúsculas o minúsculas y espacios pero que deba medir menos de 50 caracteres?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La expresión regular quedaría así:

```
^[A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúÜü ]{1,50}$
```

Acepta:

- Letras mayúsculas
- Letras minúsculas
- Espacios
- Se limita a 50 caracteres

Puedes probar la expresión regular en línea [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/S0MZLH/1).

En JavaScript la podrías usar así:

```js
var text = "Éste es un texto de prueba";
var regex = /^[A-Za-zÑñÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúÜü ]{1,50}$/;

var match = regex.exec(text);
alert(match !== null); // imprime "true" si la cadena es aceptada
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. También se puede simplificar utilizando: `var regex = /^[a-zñáéíóúü ]{1,50}$/i; if (regex.test(text)) { alert('Coincide') }`

Comment: para las tildes y "ñ"  puedes usar `\u00E0-\u00FC` y asi cubres lo que tu pones pero mas elegante hehe

Comment: @lois6b ese rango incluye los caracteres `[àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûü]`, donde hay más de lo que debería haber, y faltan las mayúsculas (que podrían agregarse con `/i`). Por más que todos quisieran tener una forma *sencilla* de incluirlos, la única forma es de a 1 (o eliminar los diacríticos antes de comparar).

Comment: @Mariano muchas gracias por la info!